# Bubble sort with file in C

Tags: c, file, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to implement bubble sort with writing to the file. I think that sorting is implemet good, but something wrong is with writing to file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fp; 
   int tab[] = {3,5,1,2,4};
   int i, j, temp;
   if ((fp=fopen("test.txt", "w"))==NULL) {
     printf ("Error!\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   for(i =0; i<5;i++)
   {
     for(j=0; j<4; j++)
     {
       if(tab[j] > tab[j+1])
       {
         temp = tab[j+1];   
         tab[j+1] = tab[j]; 
         tab[j] = temp;
       }
     }
   }

   fprintf (fp, "%d", tab);
   fclose (fp); 
   return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Were you unable to reduce the problem to just "writing an array to a file"? Did you really conclude that we need to see the sorting code, and that the problem is about sorting? Did you make any attempt to print just the unsorted array to the file first? Discovering your weaknesses is the first step toward building strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `%d` format string instructs `printf()` to print a single integer what the code tries to do is writing a pointer to an array of integers as if it was an integer.

Simply loop over your array and print one `int` in every iteration. You will also need to decide on a separator you want to use or else all the integers will be written side by side preventing the reader from making sense of them.